# How to query the same set of columns with different set of values on the same query efficiently

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I'm using SQL SERVER 2014 and I have this query which needs to be rebuilt to be more efficient in what it is trying to accomplish.

As an **example**, I created this schema and added data to it so we could replicate the problem. You can try it at rextester (http://rextester.com/AIYG36293)

```
create table Dogs
(
    Name nvarchar(20),
    Owner_ID int,
    Shelter_ID int
);

insert into Dogs values
('alpha', 1, 1),
('beta', 2, 1),
('charlie', 3, 1),
('beta', 1, 2),
('alpha', 2, 2),
('charlie', 3, 2),
('charlie', 1, 3),
('beta', 2, 3),
('alpha', 3, 3);
```

I want to find out which **Shelter** has these set of owner and dog name combinations and it must be exact. This is the query I'm using right now (this is more or less what query Entity Framework generated but with some slight changes to make it simpler):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
Shelter_ID
FROM Dogs AS [Extent1]
WHERE ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [Dogs] AS [Extent2]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Shelter_ID] = [Extent2].[Shelter_ID] AND [Extent2].[Name] = 'charlie' AND [Extent2].[Owner_ID] = 1
)) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[Dogs] AS [Extent3]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Shelter_ID] = [Extent3].[Shelter_ID] AND [Extent3].[Name] = 'beta' AND [Extent3].[Owner_ID] = 2
)) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[Dogs] AS [Extent4]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Shelter_ID] = [Extent4].[Shelter_ID] AND [Extent4].[Name] = 'alpha' AND [Extent4].[Owner_ID] = 3
))
```

This query is able to get what I need but I want to know if there is any simpler way of querying it. Because in my actual use case, I have more than just 3 combinations to worry about, it could get up to some crazy combinations like 1000 or more. So just imagine having 1000 subqueries in there so, well, yeah you get the point. When I try querying with that many I get an error saying:

> The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not
>   produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for
>   extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large
>   number of tables or partitions.

**NOTE**
One solution I tried was using a [Pivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) to flatten the data and although the query becomes simpler since it would then be just a simple `WHERE` clause with a number of `AND` statements but when at some point I get to a higher number number of combinations then I exceed the limit for the allowable max row size and get this error when creating my temporary table to store the flatten data:

> Cannot create a row of size 10514 which is greater than the allowable
>   maximum row size of 8060.

I appreciate any help or thoughts on this matter.

Thanks!

Comment: Why the [entity-framework] tag? Note that you can also use OR. [  (a AND b) OR (c AND d) ...]. If the query gets too large, collect the data in chunks.

Comment: No Dog_ID needed? (Dogs sometimes are renamed by their new owners.)

Comment: @GertArnold I used entity framework and got the query it generated from it so I just added it in the tags.

Comment: @jarlh It just an example to replicate the problem, let's not focus on the schema too much. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count them.

```
WITH dogSet AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM ( 
        VALUES ('charlie',1),('beta',2),('alpha',3) 
     ) ts(Name,Owner_ID) 
)
SELECT Shelter_ID
FROM Dogs AS [Extent1]
JOIN dogSet ts ON ts.Name= [Extent1].name and ts.Owner_ID = [Extent1].Owner_ID
GROUP BY Shelter_ID
HAVING count(*) = (SELECT count(*) n FROM dogSet)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out and see how it does with more combinations.